# If use virtualization, How possible is to get access to document files or get root access?

Tags: tails, information-leaks, virtualisation

As far as I read,  using TorBrowser with Tails, it's better than using only Tor, because Tails doesn't store any data on the Hard Disk, and because of leaks related to services running in background when using Mac Os, Windows, and so on.

Since anonymity is not priority, If I decided to use a Mac_Os as a host and install VirtualBox to run Tails as a guest, my question is: What are the risks of someone getting access to my document files or get root access?

Comment: What kind of attack are you worried about? This question is too broad as is; the type of data that can be accessed is completely dependant on the type of attack For instance, are you worried about complete compromise of your Tails VM (eg. someone gets root access on your VM) or are you just worried that someone will deanonymize your Tor traffic? Please clarify the type of attack and then vote to reopen this question.